# laravel form posting issue

Tags: forms, laravel

Hi I am using Laravel latest version and iam new to laravel..iam trying  to implement simple login where user enters data and allowed to login and redirect to welcome page and when i am posting to same login page i keep getting NotFoundHttpException error..

```
Route::get('login',array('uses'=>'LoginController@show'));
```

`Route::post('login',function(){ return "success"; });`

and my form code is

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/login', 'method' => 'post')) }}
```

when i submit the form i keed getting NotFoundHttpException error..
i used view source of login page, form action seems to be fine and routes are also fine but i done have any idea why i keep getting this issue..can anyone please help me solve this issue..thanks in advance..

Comment: try absolute url.... i know it won't make any difference but just trying to check something.

Comment: What is your url when you press on form submit button?

Comment: when i click submit it is redirecting to index.html page with error  specified..